# How can I get all the financial ratios of all the companies listed on Nasdaq?

Tags: data, ratio

I hope the question is clear enough.
I know of intrinio.com, which lets you get each datapoint at a time, but not all at once.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://www.quandl.com/api/v3/datatables/ZACKS/FC.csv?api_key=YOUR_API_KEY

where YOUR_API_KEY is your api key from quandl.

For more information: https://www.quandl.com/docs/api